# Calling Delete Method of API Controller Does Not Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

The `Get` and `Post` methods work fine, but when I try to call the `Delete` endpoint, it seems like it is never executed.

***UserController.cs***

```
[HttpDelete]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromForm] string userName)
{
    return await RemoveUser(userName);
}
```

I am using the `HttpClient`to perform the request as follows:

```
using (Client = new HttpClient())
{
    Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44332/");
    var result = await Client.DeleteAsync(new Uri($"/api/v{Version}/User" +"/xxx"));
    return result.ToString();
}
```

I have created a console application to test the API:

***Program.cs***

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44332/") };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => RunAsync(args));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync(IReadOnlyList<string> args)
    {
        var result = await Client.DeleteAsync(new Uri($"/api/v1/user/gareth"));
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I call the same endpoint using Postman it works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't execute? What happens? Can you share your other calls that work? It is possible that .NET is going through a different proxy than Postman and that the proxy that .NET uses blocks HTTP DELETE requests

Comment: When i call the post or get i hit breakpoints int the API, with the delete nothing happens, no exception and breakpoint is not hit

Comment: And what happens in the client? Can you debug that too?

Comment: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: i can debug and when i execute the line var result = await Client.DeleteAsync... it just executes and i have a breakpoint on the reutrn result... which is never hit and a breakpoint in the running api which is never hit. But if i call it from postman the breakpoint in the api is hit

Comment: 1) Run Fiddler in the background 2) use `https://localhost.fiddler:44332/` as your endpoint address 3) inspect the traffic in Fiddler

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock to me. Please add how you call that delete code and from where (console application, WinForms, WPF, etc)

Comment: @Daniel What are you talking about? CORS is for JavaScript browser applications

Comment: So i added fiddler it hits the Get and post endpoints the show up. When i run the delete nothing shows up? very strange. How i call the application is from a .netconsole app i will add some code above

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i updated the question with code from console

Comment: @MicroMan your base address ends with a slash / and the delete address starts with one too. Try removing one of them to see if that's all your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse the username from the request body (`[FromBody]`), but you are not providing any payload to the HTTP client, instead you are specifying the parameter within the URL. Therefore, your API method should look something like this:

***UserController.cs***

```
[HttpDelete("{userName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string userName)
{
    return await RemoveUser(userName);
}
```

The code below will issue a `DELETE` request against the `UserController` and pass `john-doe` as the `userName` parameter.

***Program.cs***

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44332") };
    httpClient.DeleteAsync(new Uri("/api/v1/user/john-doe", UriKind.Relative)).Wait();
}
```